# Prevent Autocorretion of a Word in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-keyboard

My client's chat app is autocorrected whenever it is mentioned in UITextViews within the app.
So if it's called XYZ (just making this up) whenever users type XYZ in a UITextView in the app, it tries to autocorrect it.

I know this is a small/petty thing, but he feels like it's embarrassing to see the app's name try to be changed for users of it, if that makes sense.

Any chance I could have that specific word ignored for the UITextView inside the actual app? Or does this require modifying the user's SwiftKey or something on a per-user basis to avoid?

Thanks for any help / direction anyone can provide!

Comment: Are you talking within other apps or within the app you are working on ?

Comment: @Harsh Citing the post "Any chance I could have that specific word ignored for the UITextView **inside the actual app**?"

Comment: In the app delegate you can use the UITextChecker API to learn a new word within your own app and will be applied to all the other apps too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UITextChecker in the root view controller's viewDidLoad()

```
UITextChecker.learnWord("xyz")
```

Answer (score 3):

A very well documented tutorial about UITextChecker given by [NSHipster blog](https://nshipster.com/uitextchecker/).

You should focus on the [Learning a New word](https://nshipster.com/uitextchecker/#learning-new-words) Section of the blog, which should give you answer

Just for the sake if people don't want to jump around links

> Let’s assume that you want your users to be able to type "xyz"
>   exactly. Let your app know that by telling it to learn the word, using
>   the UITextChecker.learnWord(_:) class method:

```
let someNewWordTheAppNeedsToLearn = "xyz"    
UITextChecker.learnWord(someNewWordTheAppNeedsToLearn)
```

I believe you can create a wrapper class exclusively for making app learn words and call it in your app delegate.

> [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextchecker/1621028-learnword)